# Programming toolchain supporting "Incremental computing" (maybe even C/C++)

Tags: code-analysis, scientific-computing, dataflow, grid-computing

I'd like to write algorithms, that prepare results for big data sets. Than, when each dataset changes, incrementally update all affected outputs.

It's called : [*Incremental computing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_computing).

Are there programming tools, libraries, compiler, program analysis etc supporting this approach ?

P.S. I know [*Incremental computing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_computing) can be easily achieved by implementing it "by-hand" with proper construction of algorithm. I just wonder if there are tools (like program analysers, compilers, libraries) supporting such approach, to make data-flow dependencies more automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Annie Liu has been pursuing these ideas under the term "finite differencing".  See http://ecommons.library.cornell.edu/handle/1813/7208